# Database connection and executing query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database created using SQLiteBrowser and i have copied this file to the assets folder. I have 1 table in the database. the table has 2 columns id and desc.

The code i use for doing this is

```
package com.example.ccc;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ccc/databases/";

        private static String DB_NAME = "db";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

        private final Context myContext;

        /**
          * Constructor
          * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
          * @param context
          */
        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        }   

         /**
          * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
          * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        copyDataBase();
        }

        }

         /**
          * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
          * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
          */
        private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

         /**
          * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
          * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
          * This is done by transfering bytestream.
          * */
        private void copyDataBase()
        {
            Log.i("Database", "New database is being copied to device!");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            OutputStream myOutput = null;
            int length;
            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = null;
            try
            {
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the
                // outputfile
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
                while((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myOutput.close();
                myOutput.flush();
                myInput.close();
                Log.i("Database", "New database has been copied to device!");
                //cmn.mailDetails();

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected Boolean openDataBase()
        {
            if(checkDataBase())
            {
                // Open the database
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                try
                {
                    Log.i("Database", "Trying to Open Database!");
                    if(myDataBase != null)
                    {
                        if(!myDataBase.isOpen())
                        {
                            Log.i("Database", "Database is closed now opening it!");
                            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.i("Database", "Database is already Open!");
                        }
                        Log.i("Database", "Database is Opened successfully in OPEN_READWRITE  Mode !");
                        return true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                        Log.i("Database", "Database is Opened successfully in OPEN_READWRITE  Mode !");
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Database", "Some error occured while opening Database Error:" + e.getMessage());
                    myDataBase = null;
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            return false;
        }

            @Override
            public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            }


            public String getT(int id)
            {
                Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TotList WHERE id = '"+id+"'", null); 
                //Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TotList WHERE id = ?", new String[] {id});
                c.moveToFirst();
                String s=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("desc"));
                return s;

            }        

}
```

In my activity i am trying to call the getT() and display the content of the column for the specified id. For this the code i am using is

```
package com.example.ccc;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);


        try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

        }

        String s=myDbHelper.getT(1); 
        tv.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The application stops running with the following errors.

```
  10-22 15:12:49.086: E/SQLiteLog(885): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
    10-22 15:12:49.152: E/SQLiteLog(885): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.ccc/databases/db) - 
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.ccc/databases/db'.
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at com.example.ccc.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:69)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at com.example.ccc.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:44)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at com.example.ccc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    10-22 15:12:49.388: E/SQLiteDatabase(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:49.856: I/Database(885): New database is being copied to device!
    10-22 15:12:49.899: I/Database(885): New database has been copied to device!
    10-22 15:12:49.926: I/Database(885): Trying to Open Database!
    10-22 15:12:50.056: I/Database(885): Database is Opened successfully in OPEN_READWRITE  Mode !
    10-22 15:12:50.076: E/SQLiteLog(885): (1) no such table: TotList
    10-22 15:12:50.096: D/AndroidRuntime(885): Shutting down VM
    10-22 15:12:50.096: W/dalvikvm(885): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ccc/com.example.ccc.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TotList (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TotList WHERE id = '1'
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TotList (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TotList WHERE id = '1'
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.ccc.DataBaseHelper.getT(DataBaseHelper.java:208)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at com.example.ccc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885):  ... 11 more
    10-22 15:13:20.548: I/Process(885): Sending signal. PID: 885 SIG: 9
```

where is the problem? how do i resolve it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query makes reference to the table `TotTable`, which does not exist inside the database.

> 10-22 15:12:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ccc/com.example.ccc.MainActivity}:
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TotList (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TotList WHERE id = '1

Comment: Oh yes! u were right. table name was supposed to be TList and now it works. +1 for the answer. thanks again